# java binary search tree find closest leaf

Tags: java, tree

Im having trouble with a method that finds the height of the closest leaf. What i have just counts all of the leafs. would i have to separate the recursive calls into two conditional statements to check each one independently? any help or suggestions would be appreciated

this is my method

```
//find the distance to the closest leaf 
public int closeLeaf() 
{ 
    int distance;
    return distance = closeLeaf(root);
}

private int closeLeaf(StringNode n)
{
    int dist = 0;

    if(n == null)
    {
        dist = 0;//empty tree
    }
    else if(n.getLeft()== null && n.getRight()== null)
    {
        dist++;
    }

    else
    {

        dist =closeLeaf(n.getLeft()) + closeLeaf(n.getRight());



    }
    return dist;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Returning values

Please don't do this:

```
int distance;
return distance = closeLeaf(root);
```

Just:

```
return closeLeaf(root);
```

### On to the real question

Here you're adding up the distance to each leaf:

```
dist = closeLeaf(n.getLeft()) + closeLeaf(n.getRight());
```

You probably just want to get the minimum of the two values (to tell you the distance to the closest one).

Comment: i thought of that, ended up just getting 0 as the result

Comment: @alexthefourth - Sorry, you probably want the minimum of those two **plus one** (for the current node).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

> dist =closeLeaf(n.getLeft()) + closeLeaf(n.getRight());

which increments `dist` for every node encountered, use a <s>static/</s>class member variable that gets incremented each time the `closeLeaf` function is called.

Limit the recursion to finding a leaf, and the value of `dist` when you find one will give you the height of the closest leaf.

Comment: would the variable go outside of the method?

Comment: @alexthefourth. I would prefer it going outside of the method. But you can also use a static variable. Depends on your choice.

Comment: i havent seen that before, i havent seen alot since its my second java class. but can you give me a rough idea about hwo that would be implemented? would i have to add another method that would increment the variable each time closeLEaf is called?

Comment: @alesthefourth. Have a look here. (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html). In short, if you can, go through the Oracle java tutorial once. It will help you get the hang of things quickly.

Comment: @Brendan Long. Indeed it is. It wouldn't be wrong, but it sure will be ___bad___. Thanks for rectifying.

Comment: if its a bad way of doing it, is there a way of doing it inside the closeleaf method?

Comment: @alesthefourth. Using member variables (fields) is not a bad thing,  you will be using them ___a lot___. It is using _static_ which is bad.

Comment: @alexthefourth. Here's why static variables should be rarely used. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766715/when-not-to-use-the-static-keyword-in-java