# Java - A method that takes vararg and returns arraylist?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm not entirely comfortable with generics and thus haven't found a solution to this yet. I have these three methods:

```
public static List<ObjectA> objectAAsList(ObjectA ... items) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
}

public static List<ObjectB> objectBAsList(ObjectB ... items) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
}

public static List<ObjectC> objectCAsList(ObjectC ... items) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
}
```

How can I create a single method that takes a vararg of T (or something) and creates an ArrayList of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just replace your type with a type variable:

```
public static <T> List<T> genericAsList(T ... items) {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
}
```

Note that you could look at how [`Arrays.asList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#3799) is declared, since it does largely the same thing, from a type perspective.

Comment: Thanks! To help my understanding, why do I need the `<T>` before `List<T>` in the signature?

Comment: It declares a type variable scoped to that method.

Comment: But I have the `T` in the `List<T>`? Why do I need it before? Why don't I need `<ObjectA> List<ObjectA>` in my original method signature?

Comment: Because `<ObjectA>` is a type *variable* declaration, so `List<ObjectA>` refers to the type variable whose name happens to be `ObjectA`, not the class `ObjectA`.

Answer (score 0):

I think a Function is a better approach than a static method. You can define a Function :

```
public class VarArgsToList<T> implements Function<T[], List<T>> {

    @Override
    public List<T> apply(final T... items) {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    }
}
```

and apply it wherever:

```
public static void main(final String... arg) {
    ...
    final List<String> list1 = new VarArgsToList<String>().apply(arg);
    ...
    final List<MyObject> list2 = new VarArgsToList<MyObject>().apply(myObject1, myObject2, myObject3);
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to have to state the class of the objects I'm passing in when I use it.

Comment: I don't see  any advantage of this approach - how is this "better"?

Comment: @Hulk, [Take a look at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530353/in-what-situations-is-static-method-a-good-practice). (It's true that you can consider VarArgsToList as utility, but i still prefer the Function approach. Just my opinion)

Comment: The only advantage of this would be the ability to mock this behavior when testing, but this would only be relevant if you are able to somehow inject the `VarArgsToList` from the outside. If the instance is explictly created at the call-site, this adds nothing but verbosity.