# Composition vs Inheritance

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a `Validator` interface with one method signature: `public List<ParameterError> validateParameters(Parameters parameters);` Various classes implement this interface.

There are also some common methods like `isInteger`, `isInRange`, etc. Should I have these methods in a `ValidationHelper` and use composition in the classes implementing the `Validator` interface, or should I make `Validator` an abstract class, put these methods there and use inheritance instead of composition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming `isInteger`, `isInRange` etc. can be used even outside of the Validator classes if they are implemented generically. In that case, they should go into a separate util class, and that class should simply be called `Utils` rather than `ValidationHelper`. Classes/methods should always be named in the broadest context where you can use them.

Answer (score 2):

Your helper methods are good candidates for `static` methods because they are pure functions and they are not expected to be polymorphic. You should use a utility class and put all such functions in it. This results in the least coupling: neither composition, nor inheritance; just pure dependency on the methods themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer composition over inheritance since the classes implementing `Validator` may not necessarily share an `is-a` relationship. They're more likely to be interested in the methods provided by the `Validator` interface.

Also, is it not possible to have the generic (`isInteger` etc) methods implemented in the interface `Validator` and marked `final`? They could even be made made `static` along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538870/java-static-methods-best-practices) question.