# when to use a private static method?

Tags: private-methods

I know that you should make a public method static if you need to access it without creating an Object of that class.

But what is the use of a priavte static method since you are not able to access it outside of the class?

Comment: Here is another variation of that question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538870/should-private-helper-methods-be-static-if-they-can-be-static

Comment: Its just a matter of preference. It makes no noticeable difference to performance. It might give a hint to your fellow developers that the method doesn't interact with instance data.

Comment: @SergiiKhaperskov Yes, But not exactly.

Comment: private static method makes sense when it is an implementation detail and it has a very localized use on the instance of a class or on another public static method